# Appending custom conditions on spring data jpa repository method queries

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

**Short Version**

I am looking for a way to have all the findBy methods of a repository class appended with a particular condition

**Full Version**

Let's assume I have a Product entity and Customer entity. Both of them extends the OwnerAwareEntity and they inherit ownerRef field which identifies the owner of the entity( It could be a merchant or a partner ). I want to have the findBy methods of the Product and Customer modified in runtime such that they are appended with an additional condition of the ownerRef. The ownerRef value could be identified from the user session.

**Example**

The parent entity class that provides the common ownerRef field

```
public class OwnerAwareEntity implements Serializable {

 private String ownerRef;

}
```

Customer entity extending OwnerAwareEntity

```
public class Customer extends OwnerAwareEntity {

  private String firstname;

  private String mobile ;

}
```

Product entity extending OwnerAwareEntity

```
public class Product extends OwnerAwareEntity {

  private String code;

  private String name;

}
```

Repository class for Product & Customer extending an OwnerAwareRepository

```
public interface OwnerAwareRepository extends JpaRepository {

}

public interface ProductRepository extends OwnerAwareRepository {

  Product findByCode(String code );

}

public interface CustomerRepository extends OwnerAwareRepository {

  Customer findByFirstname(String firstname );

}
```

This, when executed, should result in a query like below

```
select P from Product P where P.code=?1 and P.ownerRef='aValue'
&
select C from Customer C where C.firstname=?1 and C.ownerRef='aValue'
```

What should be my approach to have this appending of condition achieved?. I only want this appending to be happening when the parent repository is OwnerAwareRepository.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I used @Filter of Hibernate and then created an Aspect to intercept the methods

Defined a base class  entity with the following structure

**OwnerAwareEntity.java**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;    
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import java.io.Serializable;

@MappedSuperclass
@FilterDef(name = "ownerFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "ownerRef", type = "long")})
@Filter(name = "ownerFilter", condition = "OWNER_REF = :ownerRef")
public class OwnerAwareEntity implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "OWNER_REF",nullable = true)
    private Long ownerRef;

}
```

We set the filter on this entity. The hibernate @Filter allows us to set a condition to be appended to the select where clause.

Next, defined a base repository for the entity of type OwnerAwareEntity

**OwnerAwareRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface OwnerAwareRepository<T, ID extends java.io.Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

Created an Aspect that will intercept all the methods from the repositories that extend OwnerAwareRepository

**OwnerFilterAdvisor.java**

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.hibernate.Filter;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class OwnerFilterAdvisor {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.xyz.app.repository.OwnerAwareRepository+.*(..))")
    protected void ownerAwareRepositoryMethod(){

    }

    @Around(value = "ownerAwareRepositoryMethod()")
    public Object enableOwnerFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{

        // Variable holding the session
        Session session = null;

        try {

            // Get the Session from the entityManager in current persistence context
            session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

            // Enable the filter
            Filter filter = session.enableFilter("ownerFilter");

            // Set the parameter from the session
            filter.setParameter("ownerRef", getSessionOwnerRef());

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // Log the error
            log.error("Error enabling ownerFilter : Reason -" +ex.getMessage());

        }

        // Proceed with the joint point
        Object obj  = joinPoint.proceed();

        // If session was available
        if ( session != null ) {

            // Disable the filter
            session.disableFilter("ownerFilter");

        }

        // Return
        return obj;

    }


    private Long getSessionOwnerRef() {

// Logic to return the ownerRef from current session

    }
}
```

The advisor is set to intercept all the methods from classes that extends the OwnerAwareRepository. On the interception, the current hibernate Session is obtained from entityManager ( of current persistence context ) and the filter is enabled with the param value of "ownerRef".

Also have a configuration file created to have the advisor scanned

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz.app.advisors"})
public class AOPConfig {
}
```

Once these files are in place, you need to have the following things done for the entities that need to be owner aware

1. The entity needs to extend OwnerAwareEntity
2. The entity repository class need to extend OwnerAwareRepository

**Dependencies**

This setup requires the spring aop to be in the dependencies. You may add the following to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Advantages**

1. Works with all select queries ( findBy methods, findAll etc )
2. @Query methods also gets intercepted
3. Simple implementation

**Caveats**

- The where clause of  delete or update is not affected by
     this filter.
- If the repository contains a save/update/delete method  and if the
     method is not tagged as @Transactional, then interceptor will give
     error ( You can catch and have the method proceed normally in these
     cases)

Comment: How can use this sulotion when an entity has not any filter on it?

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan: This solution relies on the usage of filter functionality of hibernate to inject a custom condition. There could be some other solution available by using Predicates or intercepting the query generation. Unfortunately, I haven't done any further research on this as the Filter based solution was sufficient for my use case.

Comment: absolutely it's a nice solution but in my code base some of Domain model have the condition and some does not it , if a Domain model has not any filter on it the code will throw some exception , how can we handle it ? I was thinking maybe you fix it this problem too.

Comment: If the issue is that only some of the domains need to have this applied, you can create a base domain ( like in the solution, the OwnerAwareEntity ) that has the filter and extend the domains that you want to apply this using the base domain. This way only the OwnerAwareEntity ( base domain )  extending domains are applied for the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Predicate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl) of QueryDSL (or [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)) in Spring Data JPA methods.

Example:

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User> {
}

Predicate predicate = QUser.user.firstname.equalsIgnoreCase("dave")
    .and(user.lastname.startsWithIgnoreCase("mathews"));

userRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

To work with QueryDSL add to you pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
//..
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then compile your project and you will get Q-classes of your entities.
More info is [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html_single/#jpa_integration).

Comment: The findBy methods in the class are just for example. There could be any number of findBy methods in the repository and wanted to have it all appended with the specific condition.

Comment: And what your 'any number of findBy' methods should do? )) All `findBy` methods is used to define combinations of conditions statically. But `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` has only one `findAll` method with `predicate` as a parameter which gives you ability to built any combinations of conditions at runtime.