# is there any way to append dynamic where clause to all queries (find ,update , delete) in Spring Data with write an "Aspect"?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, row-level-security

for security purposes and partial data access, I need to implement **"Row Level Security"** on **Spring Data** in our project,
By Writing an **Filter Aspect**, All Entities with **@filter** annotation will be filtered, By Enabling **Session Filter**
but filter does not effects for **update, delete** operations ,
my question is: is it possible add **dynamic where clause** to Delete or Update Operation like find operation By AOP Method?
is there any idea ? any help will be appreciated

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FilterAspect {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.isc.framework.repository.GenericRepository+.*(..))")
    protected void ownerAwareRepositoryMethod() {

    }

    @Around(value = "ownerAwareRepositoryMethod()")
    public Object BranchFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

            Filter filter = session.enableFilter("authorize");

            filter.setParameter("branchId", getBranchId());


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error enabling ownerFilter : Reason -" + ex.getMessage());
        }

        Object obj = joinPoint.proceed();

        if (session != null) {
            session.disableFilter("authorize");
        }

        return obj;
    }

    private String getBranchId() {
        return SecurityUtils.getAuthenticatedUser().getBranch().getId();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more context to _adding dynamic where clauses_? What is your idea or task? What are you trying to achieve? You could debug your aspect and check whether you have information (in `ProceedingJoinPoint`) about the query that is being executed. I think it's going to be very difficult to do it with AOP, but if you give me more context, maybe I could suggest some other way.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) ?

Comment: i want to catch all fetch and modification(Update and Delete) queries at runtime ,for appending specific where clause to them,
thanks @StefanGolubović ,

Comment: @R.G no specification that's not

Comment: @elias-heydarpour Will the query (`select`, `update`, `delete`) provide some information at runtime, which would affect the `where` clause? Can you do it with [`@Where`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotation on an entity?

Comment: Unless you are executing HQL Update/Delete DML statements, this shouldn't matter because your select queries wouldn't receive any data that doesn't belong to the branch, right? If you could still receive data that belongs to other branches, you should think about applying the filter to more entities. If the problem is a bout HQL DML statements, there is not much you can do except for coding the filter as WHERE clause conditions into these queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567306/10454556
see this ,in this answer , on caveats : The where clause of delete or update is not affected by
this filter.